# Can we show that complex conjugate eigenvalue pairs produce complex conjugate eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there a quick and dirty proof to show that given

$Av_1 = \lambda v_1, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$

$Av_2 = \bar\lambda v_2, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$

$\implies v_1 = \bar v_2$?

Comment: Eigenvectors are not uniquely determined by their eigenvalues, but if $A $ is a real matrix, there is a quick clean proof of something of this kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true.  For example, let A be the identity, and any two vectors will satisfy the equation, since for the identity, every vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The question states complex conjugate eigenvalue pairs. 1 is not a complex eigenvalue.

Comment: @user5389726598465 But $1 \in \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $1 = \bar 1$. I dont see what your objection is. Unless you are assuming they have to be distinct?